# Adding more than one filter is not working for list in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have added 2 filters like uppercase and lowercase for list, data is not displaying . If apply only lowercase or uppercase data is displaying.
Please check the code below and please let me know where is the issue.

```
<div ng-app="myApp1" ng-controller="ctrl1">

        <ul >
            <li ng-repeat="x in names | orderBy:'name'">
                {{x.name  | lowercase   +' , '+x.country  | uppercase }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script>
           var app1= angular.module("myApp1",[]);
            app1.controller("ctrl1", function($scope){

                $scope.names=[{name:"ravi", country:"india"},{name:"kavitha",country:"india"},
                    {name:"Jo", country:"UK"},{name:"Hasi", country:"USA"},
                    {name:"Raj", country:"London"},{name:"Kal", country:"USA"}];

            });

        </script>
```

Here list is not populating, if have both uppercase and lowercase filters.

Comment: I don't think this syntax is valid: `lowercase   +' , '+x.country`

Comment: @DerekMT12 :- Syntax is correct. When apply lowercase only for ' name ' or onlt for 'country' , it is not applying. when use uppercase, it is working alone also.

Comment: Why don't you create a custom filter for that? I don't think what you're trying to do is possible in one line like you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write a custom filter instead, if you're gonna be doing something more complex than what's out of the box...

```
angular.module("MyApp", []).filter("myFilterName", function() {
    return function(input) {
        if(!input) return "";
        else
            return input.name.toLower() + input.country.toUpper();
    }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-repeat="thing in things">
    {{ thing | myFilterName }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
angular.module('YourModule').filter('personLocationDisplay', function() {
   return function(person) {
      return (person.name.toLowerCase() + ', ' + person.country).toUpperCase();
   };
});
```

And you can use it like:

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="x in names | orderBy:'name'">
      {{x | personLocationDisplay }}
   </li>
</ul>
```